# How do I generate the Correlation Coefficient of two columns of a dataframe as a new column variable in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a dataframe with three columns. ID works as the Identifier where I want to use the groupby command. Here, I want to generate the Correlation Coefficient between A and B for every ID. This is how my dataframe looks like:

```
ID  A  B
1   5  7
1   3  4
2   4  5
2   7  6
2   9  1
```

I want to convert this into the following data frame:

```
ID  A  B  Corr_Coeff
1   5  7  <Value 1> 
1   3  4  <Value 1>
2   4  5  <Value 2> 
2   7  6  <Value 2>
2   9  1  <Value 2>
```

This is the code that I currently am using but does not seem to be working:

```
df['Corr_Coeff'] = df.groupby('ID')[['A','B']].corr()
```

Would be great if somebody could help me out here! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this "protected"? I may not understand the rules, but there aren't accepted/upvoted answers yet, and the single answer doesn't even have 1 vote (not even from the moderator who "protected" the question)...

Comment: @Ernest Kiwele Because 2 spam answers. Already deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by selecting rows by positions by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), for removing `MultiIndex` use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID')[['A','B']].corr()
print (df1)
             A         B
ID                      
1  A  1.000000  1.000000
   B  1.000000  1.000000
2  A  1.000000 -0.675845
   B -0.675845  1.000000

df['corr'] = df['ID'].map(df1.iloc[0::2, 1].reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
print (df)
   ID  A  B      corr
0   1  5  7  1.000000
1   1  3  4  1.000000
2   2  4  5 -0.675845
3   2  7  6 -0.675845
4   2  9  1 -0.675845
```

Alternative for create mapped `Series` by [`corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html), last convert `1 column Dataframe` to `Series` by [`DataFrame.squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
s = (df[['A']].groupby(df['ID']).corrwith(df['B'])).squeeze()
print(s)
ID
1    1.000000
2   -0.675845
Name: A, dtype: float64

df['corr'] = df['ID'].map(s)
print (df)
   ID  A  B      corr
0   1  5  7  1.000000
1   1  3  4  1.000000
2   2  4  5 -0.675845
3   2  7  6 -0.675845
4   2  9  1 -0.675845
```